# How to add a column to all columns in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

This seems like there should be a simple solution to this problem, but I have not been able to find one.  I have a matrix, for example:

```
tt <- matrix(1:9, c(3,3))
```

The last column is 7, 8, 9.  I want to add 7 to all values in the first row, 8 to all values in the second row, and 9 to all values in the third row to get

```
matrix(c(8,11,14,10,13,16,12,15,18), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
```

Using lappy as follows does not work.  Is there a soution using some kind of apply function, or something else?  I'd really like to avoid a loop or something similar.

```
lapply(tt, tt[,3], FUN = sum)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `tt + tt[,3]` works and will be the fastest. For matrices, if you _must_ use one of the apply functions, then use `apply` and `\`+\``: `apply(tt, 2, \`+\`, tt[,3])`.

Comment: ... and if you _must_ use `sum` (instead of `\`+\``), then since it will aggregate into a single value, you'd need to use `mapply` and then re-dimension it, something like `matrix(mapply(sum, tt, tt[,3]), nrow = 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code where you need to create a matrix of 7,8,9 which we need to add

```r
tt2 <- matrix(c(7,8,9), c(3,3), c(3,3))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    7    7
[2,]    8    8    8
[3,]    9    9    9
```

then use this in `map2` function as below

```r
map2(tt, tt2, ~.x+.y) %>% matrix(., ncol=3)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Output

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 8    11   14  
[2,] 10   13   16  
[3,] 12   15   18
```